# migrate / copy / move dconf settings

Tags: dconf

I changed my operating system (LMDE to Ubuntu) and would like to migrate some of the settings stored in the dconf binary file.

I know how to edit the dconf setting of the actual system (using dconf-editor or gsettings), but do not know how to read a dconf binary file of the backup of the home folder of my old system.

Is there any nice way to partially migrate my old setting, e.g. for Deja-Dup?